# ３１５ vs 315. What are the html codes for such symbols?

Tags: javascript, character, ascii, special-characters, symbols

I'm unable to google the html code for the symbols like 
３１５
that look like the numbers
3 1 5.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%EF%BC%93%EF%BC%91%EF%BC%95 - I presume though that you want a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Check this link: http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/character-identifier?characters=%EF%BC%93%EF%BC%91%EF%BC%95

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/index.htm

Comment: @bzimor Your on-line decoder exhibits on top: "(this script is currently broken)". And, as promised, it decodes the query string as single-byte Latin-1 characters :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, you can use `charCodeAt` to get the code of the character:

```js
var char = prompt("Paste the character here: ");

var decimal = char.charCodeAt(0),
    hexa = decimal.toString(16);
    
console.log("Decimal code:", decimal);
console.log("Hexadecimal code:", hexa);
```

To add it as text inside an element, use this:

```
element.innerHTML = "&#" + decimalCode + ";";
```

```js
var p = document.querySelector("p"),
    char = "３";
    
p.innerHTML = "The char is: " + char + "<br>" + 
"The next char is: &#" + (char.charCodeAt(0) + 1) + ";";
```

```html
<p></p>
```

A while ago, I made a code that gets me the surrounding characters of a particular character:

```js
var container = document.querySelector("#container"),
    inp = document.querySelector("#theChar"),
    before = document.querySelector("#before"),
    after = document.querySelector("#after");
    
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  container.innerHTML = "";
  var code = inp.value.charCodeAt(0),
      bef = +before.value,
      aft = +after.value;
  for(var i = code - bef; i <= code + aft; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = "&#" + i + ";";
    container.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

```css
#container div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label>The character: <input id="theChar"></label>
<label>Characters before: <input type="number" id="before" value="10"/></label>
<label>Characters after: <input type="number" id="after" value="10"/></label>
<button>Show</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```